# Ember Data - I want to change the URL of Child(hasMany) Resource

Tags: rest, url, ember-data, has-many

I have two models. `Institution` and `Subscription`. Institution has many subscriptions. I want to query subscriptions under an institution.

I tried code

```
this.store.findRecord('institution',id).then(function(sub){
  //Set the subscriptions
});
```

The network call was `www.hostname.com/institutions/:id` . It is looking for the relationship in the response.

I want to make the call `www.hostname.com/institutions/:id/subscriptions`. What should I do?